# AMPscript works in prevew but to not on sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I have this bit of AMPscript which retrieves the hashed email address field associated with a recipient's email from a Salesforce object and stores it in a variable. If no matching record is found, it sets the hashed email variable to an empty string.

I'm using the email within a journey and I have the Salesforce data as an entry source but the email when it gets send is not getting the hashed email address field populated in the URL. Instead, when I test it in the preview it works perfectly fine. What am I missing?

```ampscript
%%[
    var @rows, @row, @hashedEmail, @recipientEmail
    set @recipientEmail = AttributeValue("Email") /* Retrieves the email address of the recipient */
    
    /* Retrieve the record from Preference__c object where Email__c matches the recipient's email */
    set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Preference__c", "hashed_email_address__c", "Email__c", "=", @recipientEmail)
    
    if RowCount(@rows) > 0 then
        set @row = Row(@rows, 1)
        set @hashedEmail = Field(@row, "hashed_email_address__c")
    else
        set @hashedEmail = ""
    endif
    ]%%


     <a href="https://google.com/5?key=%%=v(@hashedEmail)=%%" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#1A1A1A;" alias="Unsub">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by adjusting the way you are building your unsubscribe link. You should preferably use both [Concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) as well as [RedirectTo](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) functions to ensure it gets parsed properly.

The reason why it works in preview and not in send, is probably due to the link not being tracked when in preview mode. Once the emails is being sent, all the links are rewritten to go through your click tracking domain, e.g.: https://click.sapsubdomain.example.com - if there is an issue with a link, it fails the rewrite, and the send itself fails.

You should build your link like this:

```ampscript
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat('https://google.com/5?key=',@hashedEmail))=%%" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#1A1A1A;" alias="Unsub">
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it still doesn't work using Concat and RedirectTo

Comment: Question: Is there any other ampscript in the email, @Duicug also, why don’t you just hash the email address is ampscript, assuming it is a simple SHA256 hash